# Data alignment crash (EXC-ARM-DA-ALIGN) when running iOS FIPS demo

Tags: ios, xcode, openssl, fips

I believe I have successfully compiled the lib for OpenSSL Fips module for iOS. But when I try to run the demo app provided by OpenSSL (fips-pi). I ran into the exception

```
EXC-ARM-DA-ALIGN
```

with method

```
FIPS_mode_set(1 /*on*/);
```

I understand that the problem is caused by memory alignment. But since I do not have any access to the source code of the Fips module lib, I cannot debug out the cause of the exception.

Is there any other solution to get away with this error?

Edit:

I followed the official user guid [User Guide for the OpenSSL FIPS Object Module v2.0](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf)

Hardware: iPhone4s (OpenSSL Fips Module is only valid for armv7 device)

iOS version: 8.1.2

Xcode:V6.3.2

XcodeSDK: iOS8.3

Comment: What hardware, what version of iOS, what version of Xcode/SDK, and finally, where did you get your instructions for building the FIPS Object Module (the validated crypto) and the FIPS Capable Library (capable of using the validated crypto in a plug-in like architecture)?

Comment: @jww Thank you for the reply. I have updated the question to provide more info about the environment.